# How to execute several processes sequentially, without channels?

Tags: nextflow, workflow-management

Using DSL2.

I have processes A, B, C which I want to run in sequence - B waits for A to finish, C waits for B to finish.

They are not communicating via channels so I can't do A.out.collect().

I have tried making dummy channels but this is problematic and a hack. The onComplete subscription doesn't seem to let me trigger another process.

What is the correct way to run a sequence of processes which are not communicating or triggered by channels?

P.S. I am aware that this is not really the intended use case of Nextflow (which is oriented around channel communication/triggers... but... I just need to get this done.)

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you tried to do dummy channels? Maybe by giving an example. I would suggest to use [watchPath](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#watchpath) but using this type wouldn't allow your pipeline to finish.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it is not possible without channels unless you are using `beforeScript` and `afterScript`. I came up with this solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

workflow {
  // C(B(A("")))

  next = ""
  next = A(next)
  next = B(next)
  next = C(next)
}


process A{
  echo true
  input: val _
  output: val ""

  """
  echo $task.process
  """
}

process B{
  echo true
  input: val _
  output: val ""

  """
  echo $task.process
  """
}

process C{
  echo true
  input: val _
  output: val ""

  """
  echo $task.process
  """
}
```

By using workflows you can change the execution order. But it is still a hack and I would prefer something like a `next:` keyword to specify the next process.

---

And for those not interested in DSL2:

```
process A {
  echo true

  output:
  val "" into B
  

  """
  echo "$task.process"
  """
}

process B {
  echo true

  input:
  val _ from B

  output:
  val "" into C

  """
  echo "$task.process"
  """
}

process C {
  echo true

  input:
  val _ from C

  """
  echo "$task.process"
  """
}
```

Also, I am quite curious to see other solutions.